# Are free groups and free actions related?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Is there a connection between free groups and free actions, or is it that their names just happen to be the same? I'm studying groups theory at the moment, and haven't found any relation between the two, and I find it a bit odd that the names are so similar.

Comment: Free actions are free objects in the category of $G$-sets. This is probably not where the name comes from, though. They both mean free as in unconstrained.

Comment: "Free" is a common word, like "torsion-free" etc. They are not necessarily all related.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that should be an answer.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'll take that as an answer, Thank you!

Comment: I think, the origin of these names is that a "free group" means "a group free of relators", while a "free action" means "action free of fixed points". In both cases the adjective "free" refers to lack of something. In common English one similarly uses expressions "content-free", "context-free", etc.

Comment: Free groups are exactly the groups which act freely on trees(of course this is a very special case of a free action).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free $G$-actions are free objects in the category of G-sets.

More precisely, a free object on a set $I$ in this category is the same as a free $G$-set $X$ endowed with a map $I\to G$ meeting once each orbit; the obvious way to produce it is just considering $X=G\times I$ with action $g\cdot (h,i)=(gh,i)$ and the map $I\to X$, $i\mapsto (1,i)$.

For a free action on a set $I$, the maps from various sets to $X$ satisfying the given property are the free generating families of $X$ as $G$-set.